# tracing rays through a lens, issue with hemogoney (python)

Tags: python, graphics

Currently working on a project in which I need to, given a specific point for a light source and lens shape, create a 2d graph of light rays interacting with the lens.

I attempted to run the following function:

```
def trace_rays_thru_lens(c, u, d, a1, o1, a2, o2, n1, n2, colors, 
                         xmin=-10.0, xmax=20.0,
                         ymin=-6.0, ymax=6.0,
                         gfile='fig_ray_tracing_thru_lens.png', 
                         fgsize=(8, 4), 
                         ftsize=18):

    fig, ax = setup_figure(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, fgsize, ftsize)
    
    draw_axes(ax, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
    
    led_pos = c[0]
    led_color = colors[0]
    draw_led(ax, led_pos, led_color)

    draw_lens(ax, a1, o1, a2, o2)
    
    # 1. compute the intersection of incident rays with surface 1
    #    --------------------------------------------------------
    inc_rays_surface_1 = np.array([u for _ in range(len(c))])
    int_pts_surface_1 = np.array([line_sphere_intersect(c_i, u_i, a1, o1)[0] for c_i, u_i in zip(c, inc_rays_surface_1)])
    
    # 2. draw incident rays from c to intersection points at
    #    surface 1
    draw_line_segments(ax, c, int_pts_surface_1, colors[1], Lstyle='dotted')
    
    # 3. compute unit normals to surface 1 at intersection points, 
    #    with the convention that the normals point away from the 
    #    center of curvature. (see comment in Hints above)
    normals_surface_1 = norm(int_pts_surface_1 - o1)
    
    # 4. compute transmission unit vectors at surface 1
    trans_vectors_surface_1 = transmission(inc_rays_surface_1, normals_surface_1, n1, n2)
    
    # 5. compute intersection of transmitted rays with surface 2
    int_pts_surface_2 = np.array([line_sphere_intersect(c_i, trans_i, a2, o2)[0] for c_i, trans_i in zip(int_pts_surface_1, trans_vectors_surface_1)])
    
    # 6. compute unit normals to surface 2 at intersection points, 
    #    with the convention that the normals point away from the 
    #    center of curvature
    normals_surface_2 = norm(int_pts_surface_2 - o2)
    
    # 7. draw new incident rays from points c to the intersection
    #    points at surface 2
    draw_line_segments(ax, int_pts_surface_1, int_pts_surface_2, colors[2], Lstyle='dotted')
    
    # 8. compute transmission unit vectors at surface 2
    trans_vectors_surface_2 = transmission(trans_vectors_surface_1, normals_surface_2, n2, n1)
    
    # 9. draw transmitted rays from the intersection points at
    #    surface 2 to points q that are 30 cm away from the
    #    intersection points
    q_pts = int_pts_surface_2 + 30 * trans_vectors_surface_2
    draw_line_segments(ax, int_pts_surface_2, q_pts, colors[3], Lstyle='solid')
    
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig(gfile)
    plt.show()
```

(numbers were used as an outline for the function provided by my professor)
line_sphere_intersect(c, u, a, o):
Given a line defined by the point c and unit vector u, compute the points of intersection with a sphere of radius a located at point o.
norm(v):
finds the normal of vector 'v'
draw_line_segments: plot one of more line segments from point c to point p (shown below)

```
def draw_line_segments(Ax, C, P, Colors, 
                       Lstyle='solid'):
    try:
        # could be multiple segments
        for p1, p2, c in zip(C, P, Colors):
            x = [p1[0], p2[0]]
            y = [p1[1], p2[1]]
            Ax.plot(x, y, color=c, linestyle=Lstyle)
    except:
        # a single line segment
        x = [C[0], P[0]]
        y = [C[1], P[1]]
        Ax.plot(x, y, color=Colors, linestyle=Lstyle)
```

transmission(u, n, n1, n2):
Given the incident unit vector u, normal unit vector n that defines the orientation
of the boundary between two media of refractive indices n1 and n2,
return the unit vector in the direction of the transmitted ray.

This was all ran given a pre-made list of 20 unit-vectors for the rays (as a way to speed up calculations for the time being)

The expected result was for a graph that contains a point (light source), a lens, 20 rays that all reach the lens, then shows their refraction while inside and after exiting the lens. What I got instead was an error saying "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (2,) + inhomogeneous part." focused on the 'draw_line_segments' function.

(this is all being done in MacOs and in Jypyter notebook)
(apologies if this seems nonsensical, this is my first post here and i am still relatively new to coding)